# React component function on disabled prop never called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following problem. I need to disable button and for the `disabled` prop I pass function to control this behavior. For some reason it is never called. My code is like this :

```
isValid = () => { 
  //conditions 
}

createNextButton = () => {
  return(
    <button disabled={!this.isValid})>next</button>
  )
}

createBackButton = () => {
  //similar as next button
}

generateButtons = () => (
  <div>
    {this.createBackButton()}
    {this.createNextButton()}
  </div>
)

render() {
  return(
    //something
    <div>
      {this.generateButtons()}
    </div>
)}
```

This is roughly what the relevant parts of my code look like. Everything is called except the `isValid` function and I dont know why. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, `isValid` is a function, so evaluate the result of that function and use that to set the `disabled` prop (i.e. `<button disabled={!this.isValid()}>`)

Comment: Did you mean `!this.isValid()` (note the brackets). Also, There's an extra `)` in there.

Answer (score 1):

There are just a few minor syntax errors to resolve this - first, add parenthesis `()` to `this.isValid` as shown below to execute `isValid` as a function (rather than access it as a variable). Also, remove the extra parenthesis `)` between the `}` and `>` :

```
createNextButton = () => {
  return(
    <button disabled={!this.isValid()}>next</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks. I forgot i am not passing function as a prop to child when lifting state up :/

Comment: Not a problem :-) Glad I could help!

Comment: You copied his typo, there's an extra `)`

Comment: Ah true, good catch - have just updated answer, thank you for that 

Answer (score 0):

disabled should be set to true or false.
Invoke your function and return true or false from it.

```
isValid = () => { 
  //conditions 
// return true or false
}


<button disabled={!this.isValid()}>next</button>
```

Comment: You copied his typo, there's an extra `)`